# Capture HTTP Request Parameter in Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

Can Http Request Parameter be captured and stored in Azure Application Gateway's diagnostic? I check **ApplicationGatewayAccess** but the log seems not to provide request parameter.

Answer (score 0):

No. Only the below values are captured as part of Application Gateway Access logs:

```
    "instanceId": 
    "clientIP": 
    "clientPort":
    "httpMethod": 
    "requestUri": 
    "requestQuery": 
    "userAgent": ,
    "httpStatus": ,
    "httpVersion":,
    "receivedBytes": ,
    "sentBytes": ,
    "timeTaken": ,
    "sslEnabled": ,
    "host": ,
    "originalHost":
```

Other HTTP parameters are not captured as part of the diagnostics logs. You need to pull it from the backend resource from your Application.